# Do photodiodes break KVL?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, photodiode, kirchhoffs-laws

I know what you are thinking, but hear me out. Let's do KVL in this loop:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhlWbr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We get:

$$
-V_{PD}+I(R_s+R_L)-V_1 = 0
$$

Now we solve for the current:

$$
I = \frac{V_1+V_{PD}}{R_s+R_L}
$$

If we remember that in Photodiodes \$I=P\phi(\lambda)\$ where \$P\$ is the intensity of light and \$\phi(\lambda)\$ is the photosensitivity of the photodiode at that wavelength then we get:

$$
P = \frac{V_1+V_{PD}}{(R_s+R_L)\phi(\lambda)}
$$

Which is exactly the formula for the Saturation Intensity of a photodiode! ([Source](https://www.thorlabs.com/images/TabImages/Photodetector_Lab.pdf) look at equation 3).

So what's the problem?, that it is exactly the Saturation Intensity, and nothing else, but photodiodes are not always saturated.

What happens if the photodiode is not in saturation?, I can't for the life of me figure it out, the circuit must be different but I don't know how and I can't find a mention to this anywhere, please help

Comment: Of course a photodiode does not invalidate the KVL. You are treating the photodiode as if it is a voltage source. Is that correct? You do write \$I=P\phi(\lambda)\$ and that's a **current**. You make things hard for yourself by using the \$V_{PD}\$

Comment: there will be a voltage across the photodiode, will it not?

Comment: Sure and if you have an equation to describe it, be my guest. But **I** would describe the photodiode as a current source. Consider this: if **no light** falls on the photodiode, what will be its voltage? Then we do the same (no light on the photodiode) but V1 gets a different value, what will now be the voltage across the photodiode?

Comment: Okay, let's say that I replaced the photodiode with a current source in parallel with a resistance, now V_d is the voltage across that resistance, how does it behave when the current source is not at saturation?

Comment: It is all clearly described in the document you linked, in non-saturation the voltage is simply the product of the photo current and the load resistor. You might be over-thinking this.